# Using success HRESULTs in COM

Tags: com

I have some functions in a COM interface that return different success values via the HRESULT, but using the space that is defined as "successful" (i.e. `SUCCEEDED(hr)` is non-zero).

For example

```
HRESULT MyMessageBox( BSTR title /*[in]*/, BSTR text /*[in]*/, long buttons /*[in]*/ );
```

a function that displays a dialog similar to a MessageBox; it returns an indicator of which button the user used to dismiss the dialog. (I defined an enum for this with values within the space of HRESULTs which is reserved for user-defined codes).

This is fine in a C++ client; however when VB is the client, or Java wrappers such as JACOB, it appears to intercept the HRESULT and there is no way that the client can tell which successful code occurred.

Is it actually a terrible design to have the HRESULT indicate anything other than `0` or exceptions ; should I instead make new functions that have an `[out]` parameter to get which button is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most language runtimes will map an HRESULT to an exception, makes writing COM code a lot easier.  And yes, they'll ignore positive values.  They *might* have an escape for that, in .NET the [PreserveSig] attribute suppresses the exception mapping and exposes the HRESULT return value as an *int*.

But that's painful and unnecessary.  They will also map an argument that you decorate as [out, retval] to the function return value.  Which is what you are looking for here:

```
HRESULT MyMessageBox([in] BSTR title, [in] BSTR text, [in] long buttons,
                     [out,retval] long* result);
```

And now the client programmer can write something like this:

```
int result = yadayada.MyMessageBox("title", "text", 0);
```

Giving you the opportunity to use the HRESULT only for "function failed" return values, S_OK otherwise.  You can further improve it by using *enum* types to name the legal button and return values.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you recommend a book that explains things like this, and is also readable? (I made all my design decisions when I didn't know much about COM, just whatever I could find on the web; I have a lot of basic holes in my COM knowledge).

Comment: I don't recommend books without knowing anything about who's going to read them.  Most of the ones I've read have been long out of print.  Visit amazon.com, read the reviews.

Comment: I have a deep distrust of Amazon reviews! It's too easy for publishers to arrange for their own "reviews" to be on top

Comment: I can't really help you with your trust issues.  One book is infinitely better than none, regardless of doctored reviews.  An obvious solution is to get all of them.